# How do you calculate new vector based on the other two vectors starting at origin?

Tags: math

I have two vectors starting at the origin <2,1> and <3,7>. I want to find the new vector (in blue), but it has to start at the origin as well, but can be translated to that position. How would one find that? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

[image: Find the blue vector]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. Questions on stackoverflow must be related to computer programming.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to program using a javascript library and getting a better understanding of the basics of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired blue vector is (3,7) - (2,1) = (1,6).

Where a vector starts, whether from the origin or elsewhere, is up for interpretation. All the vector itself contains is a direction and length, not a position.

Comment: Does it matter about the order? Can it be (2,1) - (3,7)?

Comment: The vector would get the opposite direction in that case.

Comment: Yes, order matters. Reversing the order would yield (2,1) - (3,7) = (-1, -6), i.e. the exact same vector, but going in the opposite direction.

Comment: So we know its 1,6. How do I translate it over to the right?

Comment: You mean to the origin? Like I mentioned, you don't have to. Vectors don't contain any information about their position. You can freely imagine them anywhere in your coordinate system as long as the exact angle and length are the same.

Comment: It's not a matter of that vector. It doesn't contain such information.

Comment: If you wanted to "translate" the vector you could put it in another coordinate system that has its origin in (2,1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at these three, you'll easily find that `shorter red + blue = longer red`. Therefore, `blue = longer red - shorter red`.